# SCCM: Add one machine explicitly

Tags: configuration, sccm, system-center

I have just started implementing SCCM 2007, and would like to test it out on only one machine.  I believe I have set the boundaries correctly, but am having trouble with the Discovery methods to select one machine into the db.

Is there a way to select a single machine into SCCM explicitly, either via script or gui?

SCCM is very powerful for large swaths of machines, but I can't seem to find the simple way.

Comment: Can you create a collection specifying the ip address or mac address of the machine you want to add?

Answer (score 4):

Just install the client, and once the client establishes a connection to the server, create a static collection that contains one workstation.

Comment: +1, Forget scrips, imports, and arcane configurations. As Duff said, just install the client and it will be added once it contacts the MP.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a single machine with the [import computer information wizard](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb632330.aspx).